# Hibernate Multiple Exceptions

Tags: java, hibernate

Before I ask the question, I know there are many questions around with a similar issue, but they are old versions, and this new version is nothing like them. I mostly see Hibernate 3 questions and answers all over. I am currently using Hibernate 5.

I have setup Hibernate in my project, and my IDE is NetBeans. I have imported the Hibernate 5 JARS into my project `lib/Hibernate` folder, which is all the JARS in the `required` folder of Hibernate.

On the root folder for the source codes of my project, which is `src/`, I created a file called `hibeernate.cfg.xml` and the contents are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<!--
Program developed by Hassan Althaf.
Copyright © 2015, Hassan Althaf.
Website: http://hassanalthaf.com
-->

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connecton.driver_class">
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/telemart
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
            root
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
            correctpasswordhere
        </property>
        <mapping resource="com/hassanalthaf/telemart/users/User.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I believe those details are correct, and, the User.hbm.xml contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate MAPPING DTD//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!--
Program developed by Hassan Althaf.
Copyright © 2015, Hassan Althaf.
Website: http://hassanalthaf.com
-->

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="User" table="users">
        <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="nicNumber" column="nic_number" type="string" />
        <property name="username" column="username" type="string" />
        <property name="password" column="password" type="string" />
        <property name="fullName" column="full_name" type="string" />
        <property name="contactNumber" column="contact_number" type="int" />
        <property name="email" column="email" type="string" />
        <property name="address" column="address" type="string" />
        <property name="salary" column="salary" type="double" />
        <property name="rank" column="rank" type="int" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Now, the place where the Hibernate code is executed is the Main.java file. It is actually a JavaFX application, but for testing purposes, I am just trying it out on the `start` method.

This is what Main.java is like right now:

```
/*
 * Program developed by Hassan Althaf.
 * Copyright © 2015, Hassan Althaf.
 * Website: http://hassanalthaf.com
 */
package com.hassanalthaf.telemart;

import com.hassanalthaf.telemart.users.User;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

/**
 *
 * @author hassan
 */
public class Main extends Application {

    public static final String APPLICATION_TITLE = "TeleMart - ERP System";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
                final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();
        final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        try {
            sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(registry).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();

            User user = new User("A", "A", "A", "A", 1, "A", "A", 1);

            try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
                session.beginTransaction();
                session.save(user);
                session.getTransaction().commit();
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("views/MainView.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setTitle(Main.APPLICATION_TITLE);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

And finally, the output I get:

```
Executing /Users/hassan/NetBeansProjects/TeleMart/TeleMart/dist/run529887580/TeleMart.jar using platform /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/1586270964.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger$1.run(Logger.java:2554)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2529)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2516)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CoreLogging.messageLogger(CoreLogging.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CoreLogging.messageLogger(CoreLogging.java:24)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.<clinit>(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:58)
    at com.hassanalthaf.telemart.Main.start(Main.java:30)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$133/598547425.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/355629945.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$49/153653436.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/1915503092.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.SystemException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 22 more
Exception running application com.hassanalthaf.telemart.Main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace says following class not existing in your classpath

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.SystemException
```

My be this class is referenced internally, even not by your code. So can you check the specified class in your classpath.

**Solution**: add the required jar file to your classpath by any of the following ways.

If your project is maven based, the required maven dependency is:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

**Or** download it from [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/transaction/jta/1.1/jta-1.1.jar) directly if you are not using maven project

Comment: Thank you mate! This was quite helpful. I knew it that it was something like JTA that I was missing but couldn't find it in the lib folder of the Hibernate download.